# Overriding var_dump globally?

Tags: php

I don't like the way var_dump prints out objects. I want to override it with this function:

```
function var_dump($object, $die = true) {
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($object);
    if ($die) die();
}
```

I know how to override it in my application, but is there a way to override it globally for all sites on a PHP config level?

Comment: You could put it to PHP’s default include path and put the file be autoloaded always?

Comment: Is that the most elegant solution? My gut is telling me there is a beter way.

Comment: To me most elegant solution is to always override it on application level; that way it won’t break when you move to another server, for one.

Comment: I like using a standard include/require file with all those basic functions I need all the time but php doesn't implement out of the box. Since that's pretty much always the first statement executed, this would be a good place to put a pseudo-global override. Whenever the project is migrated or I create a new project, that standard include file is part of it.

Comment: Before you continue, take a close look at the difference between `var_dump(null)` and `print_r(null)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not do that currently (via "good way") in PHP. And more - you shouldn't.
`var_dump()` is doing right for what it's intended: *plain* output and nothing more. If you want to change that, then by definition you want some *user-defined* behavior. Therefore:

- Create **your own function**. That is what you have now. User-defined functions are for user-defined behavior.
- Or else, if you want to do it with `var_dump()` name by some reason, use `namespace` like:

  ```
    namespace Utils;
    function var_dump($var, $exit=true, $return=true)
    {
       $result = sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r($var, true));
       if($exit)
       {
          echo $result;
          exit;
       }
       if($return)
       {
          return $result;
       }
       echo $result;
    }
  ```

  so usage will look like:

  ```
    $obj = new StdClass();
    $str = \Utils\var_dump($obj, false);
    //do domething with $str
    echo $str; //or use second false
  ```
- Worst case: [`runkit_function_redefine()`](https://www.php.net/runkit_function_redefine) Remember, this is **evil**. You should not do that because redefining goes against what is function and why it was defined. It is a global side-effect and you should avoid such behavior.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the idea. Also, could be improved in static and called as `Utils::var_dump($obj, false);`. I rather for myself

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `override_function`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php to replace the behavior of the `var_dump` function. If you want to include this piece of code in all of your sites, you can put this in your `php.ini` file:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/file_where_you_override_function.php
```